# Cannot associate Event ID in Event Log using Serilog

Tags: serilog

I am using Serilog as libraries for .NET, which provides diagnostic logging to files, the console, and elsewhere.

My issue is I have stated some Logging Events in my code but when looking into the Windows Event Viewer, the Event ID assigned with my log is not associated in the event viewer. Any ideas about this on how to modify to add the event ID?

**Logging Events code**

```
public class LoggingEvents
{
    //info
    public const int GENERATE_INDEXPAGE = 2000;
    public const int ADMIN_ACCESS = 2001;
    public const int ON_GET_REGISTRATION = 2002;
    public const int ON_GET_APP_BY_KEY = 2003;
    public const int ON_GET_BY_AIR_ID = 2004;
    public const int ON_GET_USERS = 2005;
    public const int ON_GET_GROUPS = 2006;
    public const int ON_POST_APPLICATION = 2007;

    //warning
    public const int NO_ADMIN_ACCESS = 3000;
    public const int INVALID_AIR_ID = 3001;

    //error
    public const int ERROR_POST_APPLICATION = 4000;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Serilog Windows Event Logger](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/Sinks/EventLog/EventLogSink.cs) is open source. I've never done what you're asking about, but my answer is just based on looking at the source code. If you ever have a question about how to do something with an open source library, all you have to do is look at the code.

When adding the event log sink, all you need to do is create an instance of an [IEventIdProvider](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/Sinks/EventLog/IEventIdProvider.cs) and then register it.

```
public class MyEventIdProvider : IEventIdProvider
{
    public ushort ComputeEventId(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        //your implementation here
    }
}

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.EventLog("Sample App",
                      manageEventSource: true,
                      eventIdProvider: new MyEventIdProvider())
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Hi, How can I register EventIdProvider using serilog configured from app.config?

Comment: @Hooch Do the examples [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/195) give you an idea of how to start?

Comment: It doesn't show how to use eventIdProvider from app.config.

Comment: @Hooch I see what you mean. The syntax would be clear enough, expect that I don't know that it will instantiate the event ID provider. I suggest you ask a new question here on Stack Overflow. The team that maintains Serilog is good about monitoring here for questions.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing @mason answer, this is how you can configure it from appsettings.json:

```
{
 "Serilog": {
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "EventLog",
      "Args": {
        "source": "your source name",
        "eventIdProvider": "namespace.class, assembly"
      }
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

For example

```
{
 "Serilog": {
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "EventLog",
      "Args": {
        "source": "MyApp",
        "eventIdProvider": "MyApp.MyEventIdProvider, MyApp"
      }
    }
  ]
 }
}
```